# Django channels Group send dies after sending a certain number of times

Tags: django, django-channels

I am having some strange behavior where:

```
Group('chat-'+ name).send({'text': json.dumps(m)})
```

fails after performing this send 10 or more times. What is a common reason for this? I do not see any error messages on my worker, other than it does not log that it is sending any information.

Normally I see:

```
2016-10-29 04:02:37,800 - DEBUG - ws_protocol - Sent WebSocket packet to client for !websocket.send.wTXtcZZQ
```

This message will not display after a certain number of sends. I am doing some updating behavior where this send will occur every 5 seconds.

EDIT:

This send does not occur in response to a client-send. I am sending server data to the client via this group. I assume this is the issue?

EDIT:

Looking into this more, I found this message on django-channels github here:

https://github.com/django/channels/issues/107

> andrewgodwin: "...channels has code to detect when a message gets
>   requeued too many times (it's 10 right now by default) and then it
>   kills it to prevent livelocks..."

Is sending outside of the receive context such as:

```
Group('chat-'+ name).send({'text': json.dumps(m)})
```

enqueueing repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an old version of django channels. Upgrading to the current version fixed this issue for me.